# Angular - Access all ng-models in Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

Not sure if this is possible, I think it's more of a question of poor design on my part but however maybe someone will know!

Say you have several forms

```
<form>

<input ng-model = foo_1>

<input ng-model = bar_1>

<input ng-model = bazz_1>

</form>

//////////

<form>

<input ng-model = foo_2>

<input ng-model = bar_2>

<input ng-model = bazz_2>

</form>

//////////

<form>

<input ng-model = foo_3>

<input ng-model = bar_3>

<input ng-model = bazz_3>

</form>
```

etc...

I need to get all of the model values through one function, however, the problem is that there won't always be the same amount of forms. Sometimes there might be one, sometimes there might be 5 etc.... Bascially, the number at the end of 'foo', 'bar' or 'baz' could be anything (up to 10), but the ng-models themselves will always remain the same

The issue I am having is that each form will not have it's own submit function.

There will be one button at the end through which this will need to take place.

Any advice or thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about change those form tags to <div> tags and then use angular to submit your form data once you're done?

Comment: Um, I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Use arrays.  `ng-model="x.foo[1]"`, `ng-model="x.foo[2]`, etc